# Removing HTML from NSString causes issues

Tags: html, objective-c

I made a RSS reader, and I'm parsing the description, but there are HTML tags in the description, so I created a category of NSString with the following method to weed out the tags:

```
- (NSString *)stripTags:(NSString *)str
{
NSMutableString *html = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:[str length]];

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:str];
scanner.charactersToBeSkipped = NULL;
[scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:nil];
NSString *tempText = nil;

while (![scanner isAtEnd])
{
    [scanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:&tempText];

    if (tempText != nil)
        [html appendString:tempText];

    [scanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:NULL];

    if (![scanner isAtEnd])
        [scanner setScanLocation:[scanner scanLocation] + 1];

    tempText = nil;
}

return html;
}
```

This works well in removing the HTML tags, that's not the issue.  The issue is that I have the description set to be a maximum of 100 characters in length, but it's still counting the removed HTML tags in that character count.  So some descriptions don't show up at all, or some are very short.  I need to know how I can remove the HTML tags so that they don't take up any of the character count.

If you need, here's where I'm setting my description:

```
NSString *dots;
int length = [self.description length];
if (length > 100)
{
    length = 100;
    dots = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"..."];
}
else
{
    dots = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
}

NSString *description = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [self.description substringToIndex:length], dots];
```

Comment: XCode is an IDE. Objective-C is a language.

Comment: Actually Xcode is the IDE's name ... Not XCode ;) I wonder what's so hard about writing the name of the app you all love rightly ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be because you set the capacity of the string from the original string with your first line.

```
NSMutableString *html = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:[str length]];
```

I believe this sets a minimum capacity size and while it can grow beyond this freely it cannot shrink to your new size.

A quick fix would probably be to set the length initially to 1 or something smaller than the smallest expected text.

Example:

```
NSMutableString *html = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:1];
```

You could simply use:

```
NSMutableString *html = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
```

I tried with this code and it works exactly like it should

```
NSMutableString *html = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
NSLog(@"Before: %u", [html length]);

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:@"<a>this is a test</a>"];
scanner.charactersToBeSkipped = NULL;
[scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:nil];
NSString *tempText = nil;

while (![scanner isAtEnd])
{
    [scanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:&tempText];

    if (tempText != nil)
        [html appendString:tempText];

    [scanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:NULL];

    if (![scanner isAtEnd])
        [scanner setScanLocation:[scanner scanLocation] + 1];

    tempText = nil;
}

NSLog(@"After: %u", [html length]);
```

Comment: Nice catch. `[NSMutableString string]` will also do the trick, I think.

Comment: @Benny I've tried your solution and I'm still getting the same issue with my description. I've tried 
`NSMutableString *html = [NSMutableString string];` 
`NSMutableString *html = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:1]`
`NSMutableString *html = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];`

Comment: After you have added the suggested code put a NSLog [html length] right after NSMutableString *html and then another one right before return html. Post your output. This will help us determine if the error is happening inside the function.

Comment: @Benny It won't output that to the log because of this warning: Data argument not used by format string

Comment: since length is an int try using NSLog("Length %u", [html length])

Comment: @Benny It will just output any number between 0 and 100.  It doesn't go beyond 100, as is correct, but it should never be 0.  It says my first RSS entry has a length of 0, even though there's a visible description being displayed, and the second entry has a length of 47 even though there is no description being displayed.  Very strange, any thoughts?

Comment: Please show what both NSLogs are inside the function. This will really help determine what is wrong.

Comment: @Benny Ok, so the NSLog after the NSMutableString is always 0, and it will change in the NSLog after the return html.  Below are a few examples:

2013-04-07 19:08:03.576 BizCalendar[98488:c07] Length 0
2013-04-07 19:08:03.579 BizCalendar[98488:c07] Length 47
2013-04-07 19:08:26.747 BizCalendar[98488:c07] Length 0
2013-04-07 19:08:26.747 BizCalendar[98488:c07] Length 47
2013-04-07 19:08:26.748 BizCalendar[98488:c07] Length 0
2013-04-07 19:08:26.749 BizCalendar[98488:c07] Length 0

Comment: I need the nslog right before the return html so i can see it after it's modified. Is it always 47 there too? Just to clarify I want the NSlog right after the NSMutableString and right before the return html.

Comment: @Benny No, it's not always 47.  There just wasn't enough character space to continue adding them.  The first entry is always 0 and the second looks like the correct one, however that's not what's displaying in the app.

To clarify, the first being listed (always 0) is before modification and the second is after modification.

Comment: Well try Logging out the string in the stripTags function right before the return html. If it is correct then you know your problem is outside of the function.

Comment: @Benny the html string matches the length that was logged after modification, but it's still incorrect.  I think it's still taking into account the HTML tags that were stripped.

Comment: If you are using [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; for your html initialization it will be impossible for it to be the same length as str.

Comment: @Benny Ok, so you're right, it's not the HTML tags that are causing the issues, it's the ASCII codes within the description.  This one is solved, thanks for all your help!